# Surface integral of vector field over a quarter of a cylinder

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals, parametrization

This is a question set by my maths tutor, I answered it using the divergence theorem to get an answer of 18 pi, which is correct. But I was wondering how you would be able to get the same answer by tackling the question "from first principles", so to speak.

I've attached the question and my attempt at a solution, but I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong! Any advice would be appreciated.

[My question refers to the third part of this question, the one with the cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqWIu.png)

[An image of my attempt at a solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ33X.jpg)

P.S. This is my first post so sorry that there's no posh maths text here!

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: You also need to evaluate the surface integral on the ends of the cylinder and where the coordinate planes cut it off as its a closed surface integral

Comment: That doesn't yield the 18pi though, can you see any problem with what I've done for that particular part of the problem? Thanks for pointing that out though, it passed me by when writing up first solution

Comment: That was just the first thing I noticed, unfortunately I'm currently on mobile, I will give it a look over once I get to school

Comment: OK I have given it some thought, the answer definitely lies in the other surfaces, the two ends contribute 18$\pi$ overall, the other surfaces need to cancel out the curved surface. Another note is that your normal vector has the wrong sign as this makes it an inward normal, for a closed surface we typically take the outward. Second is how did you do your trig integration step? I'm assuming the double angle formula but I wasn't sure